# Get one value from database with multiple values

Tags: php

I can't seem to find an answer to this so I'm gonna ask it here.

I have 6 checkboxes in a form with the name of certifications. Each value is different.

I use this feature to enter them into the DB $certifications = implode(',', $_POST['certification']);

If one checkbox is selected my certifications column has a single value.

But if multiple are selected and submitted it looks like this value1,value2,value3.

I have a query setup with radio buttons to select records with certain values. It works like a charm when the record has a single value, but if there are multiple ones seperated by commas that record get's overlooked since it isn't exactly what it is looking for.

For example if my url says ?certifications=value1 every record with just value1 will show up, BUT if that same url parameter is set and the record has value1,value2 it gets overlooked.

What can solve this?

```
<div id="search">
   <h2>Filter Results</h2>
  <form method="get" action="index.php">
   <h3>Certifications</h3>
   <label><input type="radio" name="certifications" value ="washington"/>Washington</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="certifications" value ="new york"/>New York</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="certifications" value ="virginia"/>Virginia</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="certifications" value ="florida" />Florida</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="certifications" value ="georgia" />Georgia</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="certifications" value ="utah" />Utah</label>
   <h3>Signage</h3>
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="signage" value ="1" /><span class="label">Top Sign</label>
   <h3>State</h3>
   <select name="state">
    <option>Select State</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option> 
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
 </select>              
   <br>
   <input class="submit_filter" type="submit" name="formSubmit"/>
 </form>
  </div>
  <div id="count">
   <?php
    $countListings = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pilotOperators"));
    echo "Total Listings: " . $countListings;
   ?>
  </div>
 <div id="results">
 <?php

 $start=0;
 $limit=5;

 if(isset($_GET['pg']))
 {
 $pg=$_GET['pg'];
 $start=($pg-1)*$limit;
 }
 else { 
 $pg = 1;
 }
 $sql = mysql_query($query); 

 $conditions = "SELECT * FROM pilotOperators WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY id DESC";
 # append condition for signage (if required)
 if(isset($_GET['signage'])) {
    $conditions .= " AND signage='1'";
 }
 # append condition for certifications (if required)
 if(isset($_GET['certifications'])) {
    $certifications = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['certifications']);
    $conditions .= " AND certifications='$certifications'";
 }
 # append condition for state (if required)
 if(isset($_GET['state'])) {
  if($_GET['state'] != "Select State") {
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['state']);
    $conditions .= " AND state='$state'";
 }
 }
 $conditions .= " Limit $start, $limit";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $conditions); 

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo "\n <table border='0' class='resultTable' width='75%'> \n";
 echo "<tr> \n";
 echo "<td width='120px'>Business: </td> \n";
 echo "<td>" . $row['business'] . "</td> \n";
 echo "</tr> \n";
 echo "<tr> \n";
 echo "<td width='120px'>Cars Available: </td> \n";
 echo "<td>" . $row['cars'] . "</td> \n";
 echo "</tr> \n";
 echo "<tr> \n";
 echo "<td>Name: </td> \n";
 echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td> \n";
 echo "</tr> \n";
 echo "<tr> \n";
 echo "<td>Phone: </td> \n";
 echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td> \n";
 echo "</tr> \n";
 echo "<tr> \n";
 echo "<td>Alt. Phone: </td> \n";
 echo "<td>" . $row['alt_phone'] . "</td> \n";
 echo "</tr> \n";
 echo "<tr> \n";
 echo "<td>Fax: </td> \n";
 echo "<td>" . $row['fax'] . "</td> \n";
 echo "</tr> \n";
 echo "<tr> \n";
 echo "<td>Email: </td> \n";
 echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td> \n";
 echo "</tr> \n";
 echo "<tr> \n";
 echo "<td>Website: </td> \n";
 echo "<td><a href='" . $row['website'] . "' target='_blank'>" . $row['website'] . "</a></td> \n";
 echo "</tr> \n";
 echo "<tr> \n";
 echo "<td>City: </td> \n";
 echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td> \n";
 echo "</tr> \n";
 echo "<tr> \n";
 echo "<td>State: </td> \n";
 echo "<td>" . $row['state'] . "</td> \n";
 echo "</tr> \n";
 echo "<tr> \n";
 echo "<td>Certifications: </td> \n";
 echo "<td>" . $row['certifications'] . "</td> \n";
 echo "</tr> \n";
 echo "<tr> \n";
 echo "<td>Top Sign: </td> \n";
 echo "<td>";
 if($row['signage'] = 1) {
  echo "Has Top Sign";
 }
 else {
  echo "Top Sign Not Listed";
 }
 echo "</td> \n";
 echo "</tr> \n";
 echo "</table> \n\n";
 }

 $countconditions = "SELECT * FROM pilotOperators WHERE 1=1";
 # append condition for signage (if required)
 if(isset($_GET['signage'])) {
    $countconditions .= " AND signage='1'";
 }
 # append condition for certifications (if required)
 if(isset($_GET['certifications'])) {
    $certifications = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['certifications']);
    $countconditions .= " AND certifications='$certifications'";
 }
 # append condition for state (if required)
 if(isset($_GET['state'])) {
  if($_GET['state'] != "Select State") {
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['state']);
    $countconditions .= " AND state='$state'";
 }
 }
 $rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, $countconditions));

 $total=ceil($rows/$limit);
  echo "<div id='paginationLinks'> \n";
  if($pg>1)
 {
 $q2 = http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, ["pg" => $pg-1]));
 echo "<a href='index.php?".$q2."' class='paginationButton'>PREVIOUS</a> \n";
 }
 if($pg!=$total)
 {
 $q = http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, ["pg" => $pg+1]));
 echo "<a href='index.php?".$q."' class='paginationButton'>NEXT</a> \n";
 }

 echo "<ul class='page'> \n";
 for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
 {
     if($i==$pg) { echo "<li class='current'>".$i."</li> \n"; }

     else { echo "<li><a href='?pg=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li> \n"; }
     }
     echo "</ul> \n";
      echo "</div> \n";
     mysqli_close($con);
     ?>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Edit:

I forgot to mention that I edited these lines and tried to use explode:

```
 if(isset($_GET['certifications'])) {
    $certifications = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,explode(",",$_GET['certifications']));
    $conditions .= " AND certifications='$certifications'";
  }
```

But that didn't do the trick.

I literally just need my code to be able to read one value from a row that has multiple stored :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
 if(isset($_GET['certifications'])) {
    $certifications = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['certifications']);
    $countconditions .= " AND certifications='$certifications'";
 }
```

You need to use [find_in_set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) e.g.

```
if(isset($_GET['certifications'])) {
    $certifications = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['certifications']);
    $countconditions .= " AND FIND_IN_SET('$certifications', certifications)";
 }
```